How to have a varying data type parameter?
As you can see, I'm incorrectly using the auto data type in the log() function. But I think it demonstrates what I'm after. I'm trying to make a simple cout wrapper, and not sure how that would look like for taking any data type.
void log(auto str = "DEFAULT LOG", bool b_endl = true)
{
    std::cout << str; if (b_endl == true) { std::cout << std::endl; }
}

int main() 
{ 
    log("string");
    log(3);
    log(3.0);
    return 0;
}


Templates (template <class TYPE> void log(TYPE str = "DEFAULT LOG", bool b_endl = true)) are your friend here, but note that not everything can accept a string as a default argument and has a << overload.

If you are not wedded to having a default argument on str, I can write up an answer. If you NEED that default, you'll have to wait on someone far craftier than I. That or put up with an overload.

"But I think it demonstrates what I'm after." -- You might think that, but describing the desired functionality in words (with the code as a fallback) is better.

@JaMiT That's the title ;)

@user4581301 Thanks I'll look into templates, cause I dont even know what they are!

Glad you commented. Didn't realize I'd somehow dropped my answer into a completely different question.

@user4581301 The default string for
str isnt necessary for my needs.

@CodeN00b "That's the title" -- What specifically is "that" in this context? All I see in the title is a summary of your goal, not functional requirements. Having just a summary in the title is good (see [ask]), but it's not enough to describe your functionality. Case in point: your title gives no indication of why the first parameter should have a default value. Details matter, and summaries by their nature are light on details.

I'm not sure what you're looking for.  The code you posted compiles and produces exactly the output I would expect.  Is it the no-args call that you're asking about?

Isn't it great when compilers get more capable as time goes by? Miles is taking advantage of the very latest C++ Language Standard revision. And I thought I was getting cheeky adding in a note on C++20's concepts.

@user4581301 auto parameters work with C++20 as well.

@Miles Son of a gun. So it does. I should have read the liner notes more closely.

The more text describing what you are trying to do, the more likely the answers you get help someone else in the future. Less text == less searchable.

Note: The Asker's code will work from C++20 onward. Since it does not, the answer is written, mostly, assuming C++20 is not available.
Use a template to resolve the argument type. You lose the ability to have a parameter-less, default arguments-only function call, can't infer the template argument without an argument, but this is easy to fix with an overload if the ability to call log() is a hard requirement.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <class TYPE = const char *>
void log(const TYPE & str = "DEFAULT LOG", bool b_endl = true) 
// reference to avoid copies and const because no one expects a logging 
// function to change the log message
{
    std::cout << str; 
    if (b_endl == true) 
    { 
        std::cout << std::endl; 
    }
}

int main() 
{ 
    log("string");
    log(3);
    log(3.0);
    log(); 
    return 0;
}

Sample output:
string
3
3
DEFAULT LOG

Note: You will still receive errors if you pass in an argument that cannot be resolved (eg: log({1,2,3,4});) or an argument that cannot be printed with << (eg: log(std::vector<int>());. As of C++20 you can get a slightly more understandable error message if the template argument cannot be streamed by employing a concept:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template<class TYPE>
concept outstreamable = requires(std::ostream & out, TYPE b) {
  out << b;
};

template <class TYPE = const char *> requires outstreamable<TYPE>
void log(const TYPE & str = "DEFAULT LOG", bool b_endl = true) 
{
    std::cout << str; 
    if (b_endl == true) 
    { 
        std::cout << std::endl; 
    }
}

int main() 
{ 
    log("string");
    log(3);
    log(3.0);
    log(std::vector<int>());
    return 0;
}

This version lets you know that the requirement TYPE being outstreamable was violated, rather than spitting out page after page of templates that were tried and failed to match.

@CodeN00b Do take note of Miles's point in the question comments that if you updated your compiler and built to C++20 or better what you tried would work.

Small nitpick: log() should take its TYPE parameter by const reference instead: void log(const TYPE &str, ...) and same with outstreamable

No need of extra overload: template <class TYPE = const char*> void log(TYPE str = "DEFAULT LOG", bool b_endl = true) would work.

#include <iostream>

// General template to handle multiple arguments
template<typename... Args>
void log(Args... args) 
{
    (std::cout << ... << args) << std::endl;
}

// Specialization or overload for no arguments, providing a default log
void log() {
    std::cout << "DEFAULT LOG" << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
    log("Logging: ", 1, " and ", 2.5); // Handles multiple types
    log("Another log with a single parameter");
    log(); // Uses the default log
    return 0;
}

